# J-link CDC serial port driver problem

Tags: serial, arm, uart, cortex-m4, j-link

I have an on board J-link debugger on my Infineon Relax kit. I'm trying to use my J-link as a serial interface to my PC. It requires CDC serial port driver and I have installed it. Problem is that, I'm unable to see any COM port in my device manager despite connecting my debugger with PC over USB. It shows a j-link driver though. J-link configurator says that my debug probe does not have VCOM functionality available.

Any help related to serial port setup using j-link or general USB serial interface would be appreciated.

[image: J-link configurations]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it sounds like your J-Link Lite-XMC4000 does not support the virtual COM port. You could buy a new JLink with Hardware version >9 which supports a virtual COM port, but I think the better variant would be to buy a standard USB to Serial (TTL level) adapter and attach that to your board.

Why do I say that? You can use that cable for all other projects and things running without a JLink attached to it as well. The drawback is of course that you have to program the UART peripheral which you might not need for the virtual COM port (I'm not sure on that part).

Comment: Well you'll have to configure UART even for VCOM. Solution accepted. I'm working on a prolific serial-USB level shifter.